# Regexp won't work inside quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I use this Regexp to match text inside square brackets

```
/\[link\](.*)\[\/link\]/g
```

The text that I match

```
[link]The text goes here[/link]
```

The Regexp work's great when I test it in [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0zV2/1) but when I use it in my website it doesn't work.
This is how I use it in my Website.

```
case 'untitle':
   var html = '<script>$(document).ready(function(){var topic = $(".post-body div").text();
   topic = topic.split(/\[link\](.*)\[\/link\]/g); $(".article-title a").attr("href", topic[1]);
   });<\/script>';
break;
$('body').append(html);
```

I figure out that the Regexp doesn't work because it is inside quotes so I need a method to escape it and make it work.

Comment: Why are you appending a script tag?

Comment: Adding JavaScript with JavaScript seems more than a little odd. Why not just execute that directly?

Comment: Because I must add the JavaScript code inside html variable and I didn't find any way except appending a script tag.

Comment: What do you mean add JavaScript code inside an html variable? What is the actual problem you have?

Comment: @epascarello if you can see the code in topic you will find that I add it into a variable called "html".

Comment: I understand you are appending a script element to the page. Why are you running JavaScript via a hardcoded string?

Comment: Because I didn't find another way cause I still learning JavaScript & Jquery

Comment: I forget to mention that the html variable is inside a switch case so I didn't find another way to add JavaScript code.

Comment: Well your code runs: http://jsfiddle.net/jn0d8ms7/ and you should be calling a function, not appending code to the page.

Comment: @epascarello If you see the link in the fiddle you will find that is not correct.

Comment: What is not correct?

Comment: AHHHHH....lol....escaping is your issue....but the way you are doing this is bad.

Comment: @epascarello could you tell me please how I can do it with the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the fact that \ is an escape sequesnce so it is escaping the [ caharacter. You would need to double up the `\\` in the string....

BUT the design is bad, it makes no sense to append JavaScript.

Well you are trying to run code for certain cases. It makes no sense why you are appending strings of code to the page.

```
function linkify () {
   var topic = $(".post-body div").text();
    topic = topic.split(/\[link\](.*)\[\/link\]/g); $(".article-title a").attr("href", topic[1]);
}
```

and the switch

```
case 'untitle':
    linkify();
break;
```

Comment: by the way you forget to add curly bracket for the function.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear what your exact problem is; but you are probably caught by the greediness of the regex. Basically, its matching entire `[link]The text goes here[/link] foo [link] bar [/link]` instead of just the first one. So you need to use `\[link\](.*?)\[\/link\]` instead.

Comment: try to click on the xxx link to understand the problem [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn0d8ms7/1)